# Correctly determine view size as it appear in photoshop design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, photoshop, android-gridview

I have a good activity design that was designed using photoshop  for one of my app's activity. The size of canvas used in photoshop was **640 x 1136px.**

in this design, there is a grid which should have two items, each measuring  **298px X 342px**. if i use this measurements directly  in my android project, **only one grid item appear instead of two.**

I have tried to convert the design measurements to dp and storing those dp values in different files in my project res folder but the grid still shows one item.

- **values-ldpi/dimens.xml**

  **values-mdpi/dimens.xml**

  **values-hdpi/dimens.xml**

i have used [This online tool](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/) to convert pixels dimensions to dp

**GRID IN THE DESIGN HAVE TWO ITEMS**

[image: design]

**USING grid row measurements as they appear in the design,GRID IN MY PHONE HAS ONE ITEM instead of two**

[image]

**How can i correctly implement the design?**

Comment: Have you taken the margins and padding into account?

Comment: @Dusan yes i have. in the design, margin of the grid on left and right is 20px and i have converted them to dp using the online tool and later stored the results in their folders

Comment: Well, definitely the item on the phone looks bigger than ti should be.
The ldpi, mdpi, ... is just the approximate dpi of your device, you cannot use it as a exact value for your item dimensions. You need to take the actual dimensions of the screen and do the math or use some kind of relative sizing if it is possible (like % in html).

Comment: @Dusan  i was thinking the same. for example, when i use DisplayMetrics class to get my phone size, it returns height = 854, width = 480. am wordering how can i use them to calculate margins, grid row width and height in relation to the size of canvas used to make the design which is 640 X 1136

Comment: Of course you can do that. But before that I would try to google example which does not involve this manual computation. I am pretty sure that this kind of GUI can be designed in a standard way.